# column -t command giving undesired result

Tags: bash, awk

Hi I have following text and I need to convert into proper tab separated columns. Also preserve the aesthetics meaning of headers corresponding to the columns.

```
Ximt@@@Xypt@@@Rqistr-wy@@@Nort@@@LU-nqmt@@@Minor@@@Kqust@@@Rtqson
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-20X05:17:09.595-0500@@@Olqrm@@@VUKLRE-LK-1@@@VUKLRE-KP-10@@@MLU-2@@@5636100@@@418@@@MLU Oppl LLL
2017-03-20X05:17:11.929-0500@@@K-log@@@VUKLRE-LK-1@@@VUKLRE-KP-10@@@N/O@@@5636122@@@418@@@MLU stqtt ehqngt notiyieqtion
2017-03-20X05:17:12.250-0500@@@K-log@@@VUKLRE-LK-1@@@VUKLRE-KP-10@@@N/O@@@5636122@@@418@@@MLU stqtt ehqngt notiyieqtion
2017-03-20X05:17:12.702-0500@@@Olqrm@@@VUKLRE-LK-1@@@VUKLRE-KP-10@@@MLU-2@@@5636100@@@418@@@MLU Oppl LLL
2017-03-20X05:17:12.990-0500@@@Olqrm@@@VUKLRE-LK-1@@@VUKLRE-KP-10@@@MLU-2@@@5636100@@@418@@@MLU Oppl LLL
```

I tried,

```
awk -v FS='@@@' -v OFS='\t\t' '{$1=$1}1' input
```

and

```
column -t -s'@@@' <input
```

The result is messed up, how to make header stick with respective columns? Something like below ?

```
    Ximt                         Xypt  Rqistr-wy   Nort         LU-nqmt      Minor   Kqust  Rtqson
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2017-03-20X05:17:09.595-0500 Olqrm VUKLRE-LK-1 VUKLRE-KP-10 MLU-25636100 418     MLU    Oppl   LLL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just live without the dashes:

```
$ sed '/---/d' file | column -t -s'@@@'
Ximt                              Xypt       Rqistr-wy        Nort              LU-nqmt      Minor        Kqust      Rtqson
2017-03-20X05:17:09.595-0500      Olqrm      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      MLU-2        5636100      418        MLU Oppl LLL
2017-03-20X05:17:11.929-0500      K-log      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      N/O          5636122      418        MLU stqtt ehqngt notiyieqtion
2017-03-20X05:17:12.250-0500      K-log      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      N/O          5636122      418        MLU stqtt ehqngt notiyieqtion
2017-03-20X05:17:12.702-0500      Olqrm      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      MLU-2        5636100      418        MLU Oppl LLL
2017-03-20X05:17:12.990-0500      Olqrm      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      MLU-2        5636100      418        MLU Oppl LLL
```

To add a line of dashes under your title could be any of these:

```
$ sed '/---/d' file | column -t -s'@@@' | awk '1; NR==1{gsub(/[^ ]/,"-"); print}'
Ximt                              Xypt       Rqistr-wy        Nort              LU-nqmt      Minor        Kqust      Rtqson
----                              ----       ---------        ----              -------      -----        -----      ------
2017-03-20X05:17:09.595-0500      Olqrm      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      MLU-2        5636100      418        MLU Oppl LLL
2017-03-20X05:17:11.929-0500      K-log      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      N/O          5636122      418        MLU stqtt ehqngt notiyieqtion
2017-03-20X05:17:12.250-0500      K-log      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      N/O          5636122      418        MLU stqtt ehqngt notiyieqtion
2017-03-20X05:17:12.702-0500      Olqrm      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      MLU-2        5636100      418        MLU Oppl LLL
2017-03-20X05:17:12.990-0500      Olqrm      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      MLU-2        5636100      418        MLU Oppl LLL
```

.

```
$ sed '/---/d' file | column -t -s'@@@' | awk 'NR==2{x=$0; gsub(/[^ ]/,"-",x); print x} 1'
Ximt                              Xypt       Rqistr-wy        Nort              LU-nqmt      Minor        Kqust      Rtqson
----------------------------      -----      -----------      ------------      -----        -------      ---        --- ---- ---
2017-03-20X05:17:09.595-0500      Olqrm      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      MLU-2        5636100      418        MLU Oppl LLL
2017-03-20X05:17:11.929-0500      K-log      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      N/O          5636122      418        MLU stqtt ehqngt notiyieqtion
2017-03-20X05:17:12.250-0500      K-log      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      N/O          5636122      418        MLU stqtt ehqngt notiyieqtion
2017-03-20X05:17:12.702-0500      Olqrm      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      MLU-2        5636100      418        MLU Oppl LLL
2017-03-20X05:17:12.990-0500      Olqrm      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      MLU-2        5636100      418        MLU Oppl LLL
```

.

```
$ sed '/---/d' file | column -t -s'@@@' | awk '1; NR==1{gsub(/./,"-"); print}'
Ximt                              Xypt       Rqistr-wy        Nort              LU-nqmt      Minor        Kqust      Rtqson
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-20X05:17:09.595-0500      Olqrm      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      MLU-2        5636100      418        MLU Oppl LLL
2017-03-20X05:17:11.929-0500      K-log      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      N/O          5636122      418        MLU stqtt ehqngt notiyieqtion
2017-03-20X05:17:12.250-0500      K-log      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      N/O          5636122      418        MLU stqtt ehqngt notiyieqtion
2017-03-20X05:17:12.702-0500      Olqrm      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      MLU-2        5636100      418        MLU Oppl LLL
2017-03-20X05:17:12.990-0500      Olqrm      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      MLU-2        5636100      418        MLU Oppl LLL
```

.

```
$ sed '/---/d' file | column -t -s'@@@' | awk 'NR==2{x=$0; gsub(/./,"-",x); print x} 1'
Ximt                              Xypt       Rqistr-wy        Nort              LU-nqmt      Minor        Kqust      Rtqson
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-20X05:17:09.595-0500      Olqrm      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      MLU-2        5636100      418        MLU Oppl LLL
2017-03-20X05:17:11.929-0500      K-log      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      N/O          5636122      418        MLU stqtt ehqngt notiyieqtion
2017-03-20X05:17:12.250-0500      K-log      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      N/O          5636122      418        MLU stqtt ehqngt notiyieqtion
2017-03-20X05:17:12.702-0500      Olqrm      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      MLU-2        5636100      418        MLU Oppl LLL
2017-03-20X05:17:12.990-0500      Olqrm      VUKLRE-LK-1      VUKLRE-KP-10      MLU-2        5636100      418        MLU Oppl LLL
```

Comment: So that line with `---` should be added after aligning ?

Comment: If you need it. It's what's messing up column because it's a single "field" since it has no "@@@"s in it. Your posted expected output doesn't show it though - if you need it fix your question.

Comment: I'll add those dashes myself. Thanks Ed. Will accept in few.

Comment: If you update your question to include dashes in your expected output so we can see what it is you want (a single continuous stream or broken up under header strings or something else?) then we can help you...

Comment: OK I added a few options for you to choose from or build on.

Answer (score 1):

Also perl:

```
sed '/---/d' co2 | column -t -s'@@@' |\
   perl -lnE 'push @l,$_;$l=length $_;$m=$l if $m<$l}{say shift@l;say"-"x$m;say for@l '
```

output

```
Ximt                          Xypt   Rqistr-wy    Nort          LU-nqmt  Minor    Kqust  Rtqson
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-20X05:17:09.595-0500  Olqrm  VUKLRE-LK-1  VUKLRE-KP-10  MLU-2    5636100  418    MLU Oppl LLL
2017-03-20X05:17:11.929-0500  K-log  VUKLRE-LK-1  VUKLRE-KP-10  N/O      5636122  418    MLU stqtt ehqngt notiyieqtion
2017-03-20X05:17:12.250-0500  K-log  VUKLRE-LK-1  VUKLRE-KP-10  N/O      5636122  418    MLU stqtt ehqngt notiyieqtion
2017-03-20X05:17:12.702-0500  Olqrm  VUKLRE-LK-1  VUKLRE-KP-10  MLU-2    5636100  418    MLU Oppl LLL
2017-03-20X05:17:12.990-0500  Olqrm  VUKLRE-LK-1  VUKLRE-KP-10  MLU-2    5636100  418    MLU Oppl LLL
```

It prints the delimiter line based on the longest line in the output, at the cost of reading all lines into the memory.

readable version:

```
sed '/---/d' co2 | column -t -s'@@@' | perl -lnE '
    push @l, $_;
    $l = length $_;
    $m = $l if $m < $l;
    END {
        say shift @l;
        say "-" x $m;
        say for @l;
    }
'
```

Additional: At least in the my verion of `column` the `-s` doesn't accept a `string` as an column separator. The `-s sep` means: *each (one) character form the `sep` will act as a separator*.

e.g. having the file:

```
foo@@@bar@@@baz@@@qoo
abc@def@@@zyx@zzz
lol=boo@@@fun-goo
```

the `column -t -s'@@@'` produces

```
foo      bar      baz  qoo
abc      def      zyx  zzz
lol=boo  fun-goo
```

So, you can cleary see, that it is aligned on the alone `@` too. Also, the `column -t -s'@' code` (with one `@`) produce the same result.

```
foo      bar      baz  qoo
abc      def      zyx  zzz
lol=boo  fun-goo
```

and finally using the `column -t -s'@='` you will get

```
foo  bar  baz      qoo
abc  def  zyx      zzz
lol  boo  fun-goo
```

e.g. now accepts both `@` **and** the `=` as a separator.

All the above means, you don't need to use `@@@` as separator. (Valid for the BSD version of `column` in the OS X) :)

Ofc: the accepted answer should be the `Ed`'s one, this is only for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

not a oneliner but do the job in 1 awk (self commented)

```
# input field separator is @@@
awk -F '@@@' '
   # Ouput separator is (arbitrary) TAB
   BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
   # at first read of the file (if several field)
   FNR==NR && NF>1{
     # take the longest value per field in whole file
     for( i=1;i<=NF;i++ ) if( F[i] < ( l = length( $i) ) ) F[i] = l
     # treat next entry
     next
     }
   # at next read, if several field
   NF>1 {
     # rebuild field within longest field value corresponding to this field  
     for( i=1;i<=NF;i++ ) $i = sprintf( "%-" F[i] "s", $i)
     }
   # print current line
   7
   ' YourFile YourFile
```

Note:

- need to read twice the file (2 time the name of the file at the end is mandatory [or we need to keep data in memory ex. for a stream)
- is a bit long due to rewrinting of every field, even if it is the same